# Rejected edit then edited by person rejecting

Tags: discussion, moderation, editing

Let me start by saying this is not a flame attempt, I just want to know why when I put the time into fixing a question (link didn't work and was unnecessary messy at the bottom of the post) it is [rejected](https://diy.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/653), then the mod that rejects my edit [edits](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/14243/revisions) the question and fixes the link I had already fixed? I spent time doing this edit to make the question easier to use and fix a broken link. So why reject it if your just going to do it yourself?

Comment: Is this a problem all the time, or was this a one time event (that may have been accidental)?  What happens if a mod edits a post on their own, without looking at the suggested edits queue?

Comment: So when a mod opens a question with a pending edit it isn't displayed that there are pending edits next to the edit link? That may be why. And may be worth a feature request if that I'd the case.

Comment: Obviously, I'm not ChrisF, but if I had to guess, it's because your edit wasn't *bad* but ChrisF had a better edit that he could prepare for the question. It's not personal; he saw your effort, but felt he could make the post look even better by using image markdown, which a lot of people don't know. If it helps, it's happened to me before, and I work here!

Comment: That'd be far enough but it seems that was the next edit that used image markdown

Comment: @Aarthi is it displayed if there is a pending edit when a mod opens a question or is it only shown in there pending edits list?

Comment: @UNECS Mods (and 10k users) can see when an edit is pending for a post. It displays on the post itself and in the queue.